# Rails engines and namespacing. Cases where namespaces are required?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I'm a bit confused with namespacing in engines. In a Rails engine, where `isolate_namespace` is used,

```
module Blog
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh
  end
end
```

when is it required that you refer to objects **with** the namespace `Blog` (e.g. `Blog::Post` vs just `Post`)?

As for example, within the controller of a `Post` resource of the engine, is it ok to just do `Post.find`? When it is absolutely required that you use `Blog::Post`?

Also in models associations, assume that Post `has_many :comments`. Somehow, I was expecting to define it as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  :has_many "blog/comments"
end
```

since everything is namespaced (models, table names, ...), but it looks like `has_many :comments` just works. Why namespacing is not used in association keys, and in the case where a `Comment` resource exists in the host applications, how does rails know which `Comment` I'm referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're inside some module, you can refer to other member of the module without giving the module name, eg:

```
module Foo

  class Bar
    def initialize
      @baz = Baz.new # same as Foo::Baz.new
    end
  end
  class Baz

  end
end
```

If `Baz` doesn't exist in the current module, it will cascade down to find the definition, eventually calling `const_missing` (upon which is built the autoload of classes in Rails), then throw an error if nothing is found.

Rest of your questions is answered [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html).